# In Python, how to numerically sum nested lists of integers: [[1,0], [1,1], [1,0]] → [3,1]

Tags: python, list

I have an array in the form of

```
a = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

and I need to sum all values of the same index in the nested lists so that the above yields

```
[3,2]
```

This could get archieved by the following code

```
b = [0]*len(a[0])
for x in a:
  b = map(sum, zip(b,x))
```

Since `a` contains hundreds of lists, I wonder if there is a better way to do this. These nested lists have always the same length per run, in the example above 2, but it could well be just 1 or 3 or more, hence the initialization of `b` to `[0]*len(a[0])`.

Examples for the different lengths would be:

```
# nested lists always have 3 items
a = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]]
# result: [3, 2, 4]

# nested lists always have 1 item
a = [[1], [1], [0], [0], [1]]
# result: [3]

# mixed lengths would never happen
a = [[1], [0,1], [0], [0,1,1]] # no, this not!
```

Comment: You should add an example with lists of different lengths. What result do you want for a length of 1 or 3 of your sub-lists?

Comment: Yea...What result would be if lists with different lengths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this

```
b = list(map(sum,zip(*a)))
```

1. `*a` expands a for passing in as individual parameters for a function
2. `zip(*a)` gives us an iterator returning tuples of the first items in the sublists, the second items in the sublists, and so on
3. `map(sum,zip(*a))` adds up these tuples and returns a list or an iterator (depending on python version) of the sums
4. The final `list` call turns this iterator into a list [python 3]

With

```
a = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

the above call gives

```
[3,2]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can simply transpose your initial matrix and sum each row:

```
b = [sum(e) for e in zip(*a)]
```

Comment: Does this work for lists with different lengths?...I doubt that!

Comment: @IronFist The question specifies that they are always the same length.

Comment: OP: *but it could well be just 1 or 3 or more,*

Comment: My solution is not limited to any specific length and produces the same result as the original code supplied by OP.

Comment: @Selcuk Hey, I really like this answer just as much as Matthew's answer, but I ended up using his one because it's (on average) a little bit faster in my usecase and he cared about explaining it a bit. It's really hard to decide which one to accept.

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

Use `zip_longest` (`izip_longest` in Python 2) with a fill value of `0` if your lists have different lengths:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest

>>> a = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [10, 20, 30]]
>>> [sum(x) for x in (zip_longest(*a, fillvalue=0))]
[13, 22, 30]
```

### What you intended (guess)

```
b = [0] * max(map(len, a))
for x in a:
    res = list(map(sum, zip(b, x)))
    b[:len(res)] = res
```

Now for `a`:

```
a = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [10, 20, 30]]
```

you will get a `b` of:

```
[13, 22, 30]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the kind of operation you want to harness `numpy` for.

```
import numpy as np
a = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
arr = np.array(a)
arr.sum(axis=0)
=> array([3, 2])
```

If you must have the result as a list, as opposed to a numpy array, you can use the `.tolist()` method of numpy arrays.

Comment: The overhead of passing it to numpy seems to be pretty big, at least on a slow ARM processor (cubieboard). Sadly this is about an order of magnitude slower than Matthew's answer. But it's interesting nonetheless.